# how to remove the alsa driver from linux kernel

Tags: linux, alsa

I have taken reference alsa driver from https://alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Minivosc and driver code path from https://github.com/stadaki/alsa-minivosc-src .

If I do a `rmmod` of aforesaid driver using the command below

`rmmod snd-minivosc`

The output of the above command is

`rmmod: ERROR: Module snd_minivosc is in use`

Below is output from `lsmod | grep snd-minivosc`

```
snd_minivosc 16384 1

snd_pcm 98304 6 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio,snd_minivosc,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi

snd 81920 26 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio,snd_minivosc,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
```

an output of `fuser -v` is given below, which show it depends on PulseAudio.

```
fuser -v /dev/snd/* 

/dev/snd/controlC0 pulseaudio
```

Is there is any way to remove alsa driver from kernel without restarting PC?

Comment: Kill all applications which use alsa.

Comment: `modprobe -r snd_minivosc` might be more successful, if nothing else is using the dependent modules

Comment: Kill PulseAudio (or configure it to exit after a shorter idle time).